# CSS span after newline and white-space

Tags: html, css, tooltip, newline, whitespace

I am trying to create newline in my tootlip that uses `after` to set content, but I have no success with any of white-space values. I want it to break at `<br>` or other newline character if necessary.

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  font: 11px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 14px;
  height: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 1px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  background: #338ce6;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.info:after {
  background: #338ce6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre;
  bottom: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-title);
  left: -20px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<span class="info" data-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <br> sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum">?</span>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7v970hp/1/)

Comment: You can't put a line break (or any HTML) in an html attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put the string into content css, just use \n, html is :

```
Name                   HTML Code
- horizontal tab        &#009;
- line feed             &#010;
- carriage return       &#011;
- space                 &#012;
```

So do you want this?

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  font: 11px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 14px;
  height: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 1px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  background: #338ce6;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.info:after {
  background: #338ce6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre;
  bottom: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-title);
  left: -20px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<span class="info" data-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,&#010; sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum">?</span>
```

**UPDATE**
Also using jquery you can replace any word, to simplify I used `<br>` key with the new line, so it look like this (I didn't put the string into jQuery)

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('span').each(function(){
        var a = $(this).attr('data-title');
        var b = a.replace('<br>','\n');
        $(this).attr('data-title', b);
    });
    });
```

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  font: 11px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 14px;
  height: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 1px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  background: #338ce6;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.info:after {
  background: #338ce6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre;
  bottom: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-title);
  left: -20px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="info" data-title="'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <br> sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum">?</span>
```

With your title in jQuery you can do it in this way ,by using `\n` instant of  `&#010;`

```js
$('.info').attr('data-title','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \n sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum');
```

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  font: 11px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 14px;
  height: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 1px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  background: #338ce6;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.info:after {
  background: #338ce6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre;
  bottom: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-title);
  left: -20px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="info" data-title="">?</span>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with jquery? https://jsfiddle.net/L7v970hp/4/

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `<br>` with `&#xa;`:

```css
.info {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
  font: 11px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 14px;
  height: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 1px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  background: #338ce6;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.info:after {
  background: #338ce6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: pre;
  bottom: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-title);
  left: -20px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
```

```html
<span class="info" data-title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, &#xa; sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum">?</span>
```